# How do I actually download this "Big Sur" upgrade when everything is a dead end and all online instructions are lying?

Tags: macos, software-update, mac-appstore

I've now wasted countless hours of my life, just being led around in circles with broken links and broken commands.

My mum has a MacBook Air from "early 2014" running El Capitan 10.11.6. The bank's website has stopped working. Turns out nothing but a total upgrade of the OS will fix this. Big Sur is the latest Mac OS version supported by this hardware.

But

- there is no "Program updates" thing in the Apple menu.
- Apple Store has no mention of any Big Sur when searching. I've spent hours inside it. There is nothing in there.
- the command line commands found online do nothing (the argument isn't recognized blabla).
- when I go to the exact URL for Big Sur in the App Store, it just says "Preview" and there is no download button anywhere. ***Yes, using Safari!***

How do I get Big Sur on this thing when every instruction is a dead end?

Comment: Did you try whether a recent version of Firefox would allow your mother to access the bank website?

Comment: Is there any OS update listed as available? It's possible that you may need to 'step' up to Big Sur by upgrading to High Sierra first.